# Log4j2 - Logging With Abstract Classes

Tags: java, inheritance, logging, abstract-class, log4j2

I have the following codes:

#### MySuperClass

```
package com.mypackage;

public abstract class MySuperClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    protected void demoLog() {
        LOGGER.debug("My message")
    }
}
```

#### MyClass

```
package com.mypackage;

public class MyClass extends MySuperClass {

    public void executeLog() {
        demoLog();
    }
}
```

When `com.mypackage.MyClass#executeLog` method executes it prints:

```
2018-07-24 10:39:04,964 : DEBUG : : com.mypackage.MySuperClass : demoLog : My message
```

In the log message, the Emitter is `com.mypackage.MySuperClass`, but I would like to have `com.mypackage.MyClass` as the Emitter.

- `com.mypackage.MySuperClass` is extended by multiple class
- I cannot pass `Class` as argument to the `LogManager.getLogger()` by calling `getClass()` from `MySuperClass` since it is `static`. To me using `static` is a good idea, as the actual implementation is in JSF Managed Bean.

How can I achieve this?

*There is a similar question was asked here: [Java Logging With Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160540/java-logging-with-abstract-classes), but it is not providing me with a solution.*

### Update - 1

- If the `Logger` in `MySuperClass` is defined as `private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());`, still the Emitter is `com.mypackage.MySuperClass`.
- If I define

  ```
  protected abstract Logger getLogger();
  ```

  in `MySuperClass` and implement it as

  ```
  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

  @Override
  protected Logger getLogger() {
      return logger;
  }
  ```

  in `MyClass` the Emitter is the same, i.e., `com.mypackage.MySuperClass`.

### Update - 2

If I define

```
protected abstract Logger getLogger();
```

in `MySuperClass` and implement it as

```
private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);

@Override
protected Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}
```

in `MyClass` the Emitter is the same, i.e., `com.mypackage.MySuperClass`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? The logger is typically correlated with the class in which the logging takes place. Here, you perform the logging in `MySuperClass` so having it logged under `MyClass` could be misleading.

Comment: i don't get why the answer you linked to isn't ok, it seems like the normal way of accomplishing this kind of thing. using static seems like a bad idea to me (but so does using JSF fwiw).

Comment: Is there any particular reason for such approach? Resources?

Comment: @NathanHughes please check my update

Comment: shouldn't you define the logger in MyClass as `LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class)` ?

Comment: @NathanHughes, thank you for your quick response, I tried, but it's the same. I suppose it's something to do with Log4j2 itself.

Comment: @TapasBose Please, let me know if my answer solved your problem (or why it hasn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to migrate the `LOGGER` constant to all the leaf subclasses, and then make it accessible through a protected abstract method, like below:

```
public abstract class MySuperClass {

    protected void demoLog() {
        logger().debug("My message");
    }

    protected abstract Logger logger();
}

public class MyClass extends MySuperClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void executeLog() {
        demoLog();
    }

    @Override
    protected Logger logger() {
        return LOGGER;
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: I didn't look at the link you provided, and now that I did I noticed that my answer is an analog of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29509427/2032415), so - as far as I understand - it's not a solution you look for.

---

### The Actual Answer

OK, so what this question is about (and what you mean by "emitter") is the [Log4j2 "class" conversion pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) (obtained using `%C` or `%class`), and not the `Logger`-related pattern (obtained using `%c` or `%logger`).

Consider this `log4j2.xml` configuration file related to your example:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="loggerVsClassAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="Logger=%logger | Class: %class | %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mypackage" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="loggerVsClassAppender"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

When you run **your** code using this configuration, the output you get is:

```
Logger=com.mypackage.MySuperClass | Class: com.mypackage.MySuperClass | My message
```

When you run **my** code using this configuration, the output you get is:

```
Logger=com.mypackage.MyClass | Class: com.mypackage.MySuperClass | My message
```

As you can see, appropriate `Logger` is being used in my code, but `Class` remains the same.

Now here's an excerpt from the description of the [`%class` conversion pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout):

> Outputs the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the
>   logging request. [...]
>
> Generating the class name of the caller (location information) is an
>   expensive operation and may impact performance. Use with caution.

As you can see, this is the class name as retrieved from the stack trace at call site of the `Logger.debug` method.

To conclude, you **cannot** change this particular value because `MySuperClass` is where the call actually happens. However, what you **can** do is replacing the `%class` conversion pattern with the `%logger` conversion pattern to get the expected result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, though please check my update.

Comment: @TapasBose Thanks! I updated my answer - I hope it helps.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski You have this backwards. The name of the logger is calculated when the logger is instantiated. Typically it is the name of the class the logger resides in. On the other hand, the class will be the name of the class that called the logger method. It will change depending on which class made the call. So if you want to always print the name of the class that called the log method you must configure the layout to print the class, not the logger.

Comment: @rgoers Your description is right, and I'm pretty sure I got things right :) Perhaps you didn't read the question carefully enough, or perhaps you understand "class that called the logger method" differently. The OP complains that executing `MyClass.executeLog` -> `MySuperClass.demoLog` -> `MySuperClass.LOGGER.debug` prints `MySuperClass` (as it should). Even after changing the last part to `MySuperClass.logger().debug` (where now `Logger` = `MyClass`), the OP still sees `MySuperClass` (as `debug` **is** called in `MySuperClass`). Hence my conclusion that he uses `%class` instead of `%logger`.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski, defining the instance of `Logger` in the superclass as: `private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());` and changing the patter layout to `%c` from `%C` did the trick. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski - Your solution finished off with "what you can do is replacing the %class conversion pattern with the %logger conversion pattern to get the expected result". That is exactly backwards. He needed to change from %logger (or %c) to %Class (or %C).

Comment: @rgoers You're right about what my solution finished off with. And that's precisely what the OP did, as he himself stated in [the comment above yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496770/log4j2-logging-with-abstract-classes?noredirect=1#comment90105159_51498806): "changing the pattern layout **to** `%c` **from** `%C` did the trick" :)

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski I am not sure how we can be reading the same thing and not seeing it the same way.  %c is the logger name. %C is the class name. You told him to replace the class conversion character (%C) to the logger conversion pattern (%c). He got it working by doing the exact opposite.

Comment: @rgoers I am not sure either :) Have you tested this? Because I have. Do you at least agree that `%c` (`%logger`) prints the `Logger` name  (which can generally be **anything**), and `%C` (`%Class`) prints the class name (which is the name of the class in which the called `log` method *physically* resides, and not the name of the *instantiated* class). In my answer, I've shown that `%C` always prints `MySuperClass` (because `debug` is *physically* there), even though it's called on an instance of `MyClass`. If I got something wrong, please show me where.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski What you have said above is correct, with one correction. If MySuperClass contains the Logger then demoLog(), as shown in the question will always reflect that class, regardless of %c or %C, because the method resides there. If the executeLog method had a call to LOGGER.debug() instead of a call to demoLog() then %c would print the logger name (MySuperClass) but %C would reflect MyClass, because that is the class containing the call to logger.debug. I am not sure what you mean by the instantiated class, as MyClass is both the physical and instantiated class.

Comment: @rgoers Well, then it seems we agree as to the principles, and yet we see the implications differently :) To clarify: 1) By "If the `executeLog` method had a call to `LOGGER.debug()`" you implicitly mean "and if `LOGGER` were `protected static` in `MySuperClass`", right? I agree. 2) Do you agree, then, that in the question and in all the answers `%C` always prints `MySuperClass`? 3) By *physically* I meant where the method is *defined*: `demoLog` is called *on an instance* of `MyClass`, yet it's a method *inherited* from (and *defined in*) `MySuperClass` (hence `%C` -> `MySuperClass`).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski StackOverflow is complaining about the length of this discussion. Instead of following up here I will find a place to clarify the difference between %c and %C, with examples, in the Log4j documentation.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Please see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/usage.html

Comment: @rgoers I really appreciate your preparing such a detailed manual page! You'll find my suggestions regarding this manual page in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177406/static-vs-non-static-log4j2-loggers). As to our discussion, the OP wanted the call to `MyClass.demoLog` to print `MyClass` (this corresponds to your points 1-2 and 7-8 in the manual). As you can see, the **only** time `MyClass` is printed there is point **7**, which corresponds to using the **`%logger`** pattern, and which proves my point. I hope it is convincing for you this time :)

Answer (score -1):

Dont make it static. Loggers are shared among the "same key" so they will be shared between instances of the same class.

Comment: Making a logger static has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @rgoers ofc it does as non static context would allow you to `this.getClass()` creating 1 logger instance per inheriting class in result. Besides, as you can see, accepted resolutio is based on making loggers non-static (see comments).

Comment: The accepted answer has nothing to do with the logger being static. It has to do with whether the format uses %c (the name of the logger) or %C (the name of the class containing the method calling the logging method). It is irrelevant whether the Logger is declared static or not.

Comment: Cant you see that OP had to change to nonstatic logger? Check comments.

Comment: I will say it one last time. Whether the logger is static or not is irrelevant. All that matters is %C is used. I have a good idea how this works since I wrote the code.

Comment: @rgoers Im glad that was your last comment. Answer is more than valid.