# How to override instance variable in Base class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to override instance variable of base class in Java.
I have this scenario.

```
class base {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(base.class);

}

class childA extends base
{
    // uses a lot of methods of base but should log childA instead of base
    // protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(childA.class);
}

class childB extends base
{
     //uses a lot of methods of base but should log childB instead of base
    // protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(childB.class);
}
```

Is the only solution to solve this, to leave the Logger in base unitinitalised and then pass it in the constructor of the base ??

Comment: No - fields are never overridden in Java; only methods are.

Comment: Your LOGGER is not an _instance_ variable.

Comment: This [***smells***](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html) like a *premature optimization* to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it certainly smells of _something_ premature, but optimization? How is using a different logger name an optimization?

Comment: @k314159 I agree, I think minimizing duplication is more like it, the OP wishes the class being passed to the logger was a different one based on the instance being used and they have to initialize it in every class.

Comment: You could make this be an instance method called `getLogger()` which instantiated a weak map based on the instance type using `getClass()`. `getLogger()` is responsible for making sure just one logger is created per class. Or maybe one logger per instance is not a problem, and that is what @k314159 meant by optimization (minimizing the number of logger instances).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160613/227299

Comment: @JuanMendes That is what I meant by optimization. I would probably make `logger` private. And have one per type. And not worry about optimizing my `logger` further. Until I had to. Sometimes one can log too much.

Comment: @JuanMendes there is no need to introduce your own map, because `LoggerFactory` already does this.

Comment: @k314159 You're correct, so a base method `getLogger() {return LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass())}` is good enough, as is suggested in the answer I linked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Logging With Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160540/java-logging-with-abstract-classes)